# get width of a div which was generated by javascript on runtime

Tags: dhtmlx

I have few columns which was generated by dhtmlx's javascript. The column was generated on run time which means that if I tried to view the source code of the page using the Chrome's View Page Source, I won't be able to see the generated code. But I can see the generated code by right clicking on the element and select 'Inspect Element'. So here's a part of the generated code that I copy pasted from 'Inspect Element':

```
   <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container dhx_scheduler_grid" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div class="dhx_cal_header" style="width: 1148px; height: 20px; left: -1px; top: 60px;">
        <div class="dhx_grid_line">
            <div style="width:169px;">Start Date</div>
            <div style="width:169px;">Time</div>
            <div style="width:169px;">Event</div>
            <div style="width:169px;">Location</div>
            <div style="width:169px;">Stakeholders</div>
            <div style="width:169px;">Type</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_data" style="width: 1148px; height: 506px; left: 0px; top: 81px; overflow-y: auto;">
        <div>
            <div class="dhx_grid_v_border" style="left:184px" id="imincol0"></div>
            <div class="dhx_grid_v_border" style="left:370px" id="imincol1"></div>
            <div class="dhx_grid_v_border" style="left:556px" id="imincol2"></div>
            <div class="dhx_grid_v_border" style="left:742px" id="imincol3"></div>
            <div class="dhx_grid_v_border" style="left:928px" id="imincol4"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_grid_area"><table></table></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the column width of imincol0, imincol1, imincol2 and so on which you can see at the last part of the code. I have tried few methods to get the width of the columns with these ids but to no avail. I'll always get null.

Comment: is there any way I can know and report the jerk who vote down my question without any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery you could do this:

var x = $('#imincol0').width();

If you're using pure js you could try this:
var x = document.getElementById('imincol0').offsetWidth;